# JavaScript LocalStorage of Array with String Keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

If i save my array in the localStorage the values saved with String keys are getting lost.

Example:

```
var myArray = [];

myArray["key1"] = "value1";
myArray[123] = "value2";
```

Everything works and the output of the following works:

```
myArray["key1"] => value1
myArray[123] => value2
```

Now if i store the array with something like:

```
localStorage.setItem('myStoredArray',JSON.stringify(myArray));
var myArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myStoredArray'));
```

The output is missing the value assigned with a String Key:

```
myArray["key1"] => undefined
myArray[123] => value2
```

Am i doing something wrong ,should it work or is there another way to save it that i have my values assigned with String keys?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to `parse` it before reading it..

Comment: I missed it in my example. That's not the problem. Otherwise the rest wouldn't have worked

Comment: @Rayon Thanks anyways

Comment: Is `key1` a variable ?

Comment: @Rayon no its a String

Comment: there are no associative arrays in javascript. you should use an object.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you for your answer. Could you provide a very short example how i would do my example with an object that could be saved with integer and String keys?

Comment: You are adding a property to an array object. It's not serialized as JSON. So the parsed/new array doesn't have such property. That's not how JSON works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no associative arrays in JavaScript. You should be using an object which will convert all keys to strings.

```
var myObj = {}; // <<< change here

myObj["key1"] = "value1";
myObj[123] = "value2";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll accept this as soon as it lets me!

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Daniel in the comments, your array isn't just badly persisted, it's badly created.

You can easily see it in your browser's console :

```
>var myArray = [];
<undefined
>myArray["key1"] = "value1";
<"value1"
>myArray
<[]
```

As you can see, trying to assign a value to an array through a String key doesn't work.

You can try using [ES6 Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or an object.

Since Daniel already answered with the Object method, here's the Map one :

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("key1", "value1");
myMap.set("123", "value2");
```

And the advantage of a Map is a somewhat easier iteration :

```
for (var [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
```